# MyBatis query in a for loop

Tags: java, jquery, spring, orm, mybatis

I'm using Java, Spring boot and MyBatis.
Consider that I have a list of hashMap objects like this :

```
[
   { "filterFunction": "GreaterEquals": "filterValue": 1000, "targetField": "balance"},
   { "filterFunction": "like": "filterValue":"Mike", "targetField": "name"},
]
```

How can I convert it to a query ?
in myBatis xml file I want to have a loop and for each list item add a condition (WHERE clause).

so my WHERE query should be dynamic and in a loop.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a mix-up with comma and colon, but it would look something like this if I understand correctly.

```xml
<select id="select" resultType="domain.User">
  select * from users
  <where>
    <foreach collection="list" item="x" separator="and">
      ${x.targetField}
      <choose>
        <when test="x.filterFunction == 'GreaterEquals'">
          >=
        </when>
        <when test="x.filterFunction == 'LessEquals'">
          &lt;=
        </when>
        <when test="x.filterFunction == 'like'">
          like
        </when>
      </choose>
      #{x.filterValue}
    </foreach>
  </where>
</select>
```

A few notes:

1. As it's XML, `<` must be escaped as `&lt;` or written in CDATA i.e. `<![CDATA[<]]>`.
2. You must ensure that the value of `targetField` is a valid column name because `${}` has to be used for column names in the statement. See the [FAQ](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for the details.

Off-topic:

- You may also be able to use SQL provider. There are some examples in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html).